# Рисование фона игры

Tags: java, android, canvas

Рисую фон для *android*-игры, состоящий из клеток. Сейчас каждую клетку рисую на *canvas* в цикле. Такой способ меня не устраивает.

Есть ли возможность не перерисовывать фон каждый раз при обновлении *canvas*, а перерисовывать только необходимые объекты? Во *Flash* я использовал слои для этого, а тут как реализовать такое?

Comment: Мой ответ может и не будем самым верным для вас, но есть такая штука, как FPS - это количество кадров в секунды, так вот он говорит сколько раз за секунду ПЕРЕРИСУЕТСЯ экран, может в вашей ситуации лучше не придумаешь, единственное не нужно создавать объекты в таком цикле, там только рисовать

Comment: fps - не "перерисуется", а "перерисовывается" как минимум. Если в цикле обновлять экран и код будет простым, то fps будет большим, если в коде куча сложных вычислений - fps заметно упадет. Т.е. fps это следствие, а не причина

Comment: "По вашему это неверное утверждение?" - нет, неверное. FPS показывает сколько кадров отрисовалось, а не сколько их отрисуется. У вас сейчас один шарик на экране скачает - fps одно, через секунду их стало больше миллиона - fps просело. Я про это и писал - fps только следствие, он показывает результат отрисовки, а не задает ее

Comment: на самом деле рассматривал вариант перерисовки только тех ячеек которые меняются, но этот вариант отпадает из за возрастающей сложности вычислений. Вот представьте, что на карте есть около 50-100 движущихся объектов. Придётся в каждом кадре проверять их координаты и сравнивать с ячейками.

Answer (score 2):

Java начал изучать два-три дня назад, но работал с Canvas в javascript.

У вас сейчас примерно такой алгоритм:

```
цикл {
    нарисовать ячейку (клетку)
}
```

Почему бы вам не создать класс: *CanvasCell*, с методами
P.S. c синтаксисом могут быть проблемы

```
public class CanvasCell {
    public int x;
    public int y;
    public int width; // может быть и вещественным
    public int height;
    public boolean isChange = false; // изменилась ли наша ячейка
    public void draw() {
       /* 
           контекст Canvas можно передавать в параметрах
           в этой ф-ции, используя поля, рисуем клетку
       */
    }

    /* конструктор */
    public CanvasCell(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
        /* тут присваиваем значения */
    }
}

А потом создаем наши экземпляры

СanvasCell[] cells = []; // наш массив ячеек;
```

**Где же тут оптимизация**, спросите вы? 
Оптимизация в том, что мы при следующем рендинге будем рисовать только те ячейки, которые изменились, проверять по полю *isChange*. В экземпляре будет хранится вся нужна информация ( коориданты, размер и так далее) поэтому перерисовать будет не сложно + это потом легко можно будет масштабировать ( добавить новое свойство ).

**Итого**: идея в том, что бы был доступ к каждому объекту на Canvas, тогда можно имитировать слои, использование ООП тут идеально подходит

P.S. Саму реализацию, к сожалению, не смогу написать, еще не знаком со всей java(